# how to return 404 and 200 in nodeJS azure storage?

Tags: node.js, azure

I need return 404 if queue message in azure storage is failed or return 200 if message is created

I have this code

```
app.post('/enviarconsulta', (req, res) => {
    var result;
    var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=telemedicinastorage;AccountKey=key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net');
    
    queueSvc.createMessage('turnosqueue12', JSON.stringify(req.body), function(error, results, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        };
    });

    res.status(200)
        .json({
            status: 'succes',
            data: result,
        });
});
```

but it is always returning 200, I need to change that if there was an error in

```
if (error) {

    console.log(error);
      
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to respond in the callback function of createMessage function.

```
app.post('/enviarconsulta', (req, res) => {
    var result;
    var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=telemedicinastorage;AccountKey=key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net');
    
    queueSvc.createMessage('turnosqueue12', JSON.stringify(req.body), function(error, results, response) {
        if (error) {
            res.status(404).json({
                status: 'error',
                data: result,
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                status: 'succes',
                data: result,
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "Cannot POST / " (FRONTEND)


its my code fetch: 
function enviarConsulta(endpoint, jsonObj) {
    fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: jsonObj
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            redirect('enviado');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            
        });
}

Comment: Well, this `Cannot POST /` means you are not posting to `/enviarconsulta` but to `/` and you don't have a handler `app.post('/', ... ` This means the `endPoint` variable is `/`

Comment: okey, sorry im amateur, but i dont understand ... should i add an endpoint just for /? or how would it be? can you explain it to me in another way

Comment: the variable endpoint contain this "http://localhost:6420/enviarconsulta"

Comment: If the error says `Cannot POST /` it means you are not posting to `/enviarconsulta` and if you say *the variable endpoint contain this "localhost:6420/enviarconsulta"* then there's something else going on i can't see from the code you have shown. Every browser has a Developer tools so use it to see what requests you are making to the server. You will se the address you posted to.